# NGINX Buffer parameters causing issues with Python requests library

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, python, buffer, requests

'm having problems uploading files through the Python requests library when I activate the parameters below in my NGINX proxy (where the connection goes)

proxy_buffering off;

proxy_request_buffering off;

Through curl I can successfully upload:

- It returns HTTP/200 on authentication, then HTTP/307 pro redirect through NGINX proxy and HTTP/201 to inform that the file was created successfully.

Through Python requests lib:

- It returns HTTP/200 on authentication, then HTTP/307 and soon after the client has an error that is not recorded in the NGINX log.
  Does anyone know if it is necessary to add any additional parameters so that I can upload through requests with these parameters active?

Thanks

I've tried to update the library without success.